# Null 500 error on copy

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been receiving an extremely high rate of null errors from the Google Drive API when attempting to execute copy commands on a document I may or may not have permission to copy.

Here is the code used to copy a file to drive.

```
copyDriveFile = (file, callback) ->
    driveRequest({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/#{file.id}/copy?key=omitted"
        method: "POST"
        params:
            fileId: file.id
        json:
            title: file.name
        jwt: 
            email: "my-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
            keyFile: "file-key.pem"
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        },(err, res, body) ->
            callback err, res, body
            )
```

We are receiving response in the following format: `{"error":{"code":500,"message":null}}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any common factors you can identify? Is it always the same file? Same file type?

Comment: It appears to always occur on /copy calls when we have just recently gained permission to copy that document from the document owner.

Comment: Do those same files later copy without error?

Comment: Yes  generally after roughly 10 seconds or five tries the copy succeeds.

Comment: When you say "recently gained permission", how recent are we talking about? Minutes? Seconds?

Comment: Seconds. Is there an amount of time that needs to be waited after we gain permission to copy the document? This is the code we are using to gain permission to the document: http://imgur.com/VG0T4tI

Comment: It may take some time for the permission change to replicate through our datacenters. It may be best to add some more time between the permission change and the copy, or use the original owner to make the copy, etc.

Comment: Interesting idea to use the original owner to make a copy. I hadn't thought of that since we are using a services account, and I was under the impression that you couldn't assign a new owner via a copy, just copy the file using the target account.

Comment: @TJC did this ever get resolved?

Comment: I havent had the time to attempt to switch my copy process, but no there was no resolution for the actual null error issue. I simply implemented a linear backoff that waits 1 second between tries for a maximum of 5 tries, and then gives the user an error.